# Does casting pass without a trace prevent other verbal component spells?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, stealth

The PHB states under the spell p. 264

> A veil of shadows and silence radiates from you,
>   masking you and your companions from detection.
>   For the duration, each creature you choose within 30
>   feet of you (including you) has a +10 bonus to Dexterity
>   (Stealth) checks and can’t be tracked except by magical
>   means. A creature that receives this bonus leaves
>   behind no tracks or other traces of its passage.

The line "shadows and silence radiates from you" leaves me questioning if this spell works similar to silence spell and if so, would that prevent any verbal component spells used by the **other creatures** in the area of effect?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It is a *veil* of shadows and silence. A real veil is a kind translucent curtain (either as a room/window hanging, or part of one's clothing). A veil of *silence* would block most but not all sound — hence why you get merely a very good bonus to Stealth rather than some explicit effect that says you're impossible to detect by sound.

A veil — being merely a screen — of shadows and silence only makes it harder for those outside to easily perceive those inside the area of effect. It doesn't say that spellcasting that requires verbal components is made impossible, or that perception for those inside is at all impaired (i.e., those inside can see and hear just fine!), so the interior area is unaffected.

Comment: Of course, making a noise of any kind may prevent you from using Dexterity (Stealth) or put disadvantage on the check

Comment: @DaleM Interesting point… I think though that it probably won't matter very often, as the only time you'll be rolling Stealth within PwT is when you *are* doing something and trying to be Stealthy about it — since it provides a bonus, not auto-checks or something. Whether you can cast a V spell stealthily is probably a matter of DM ruling.

Comment: There are some spells that require the target to be able to hear and understand the caster (suggestion and geas spring to mind). As there is no stated in game effect to the contrary the caster, RAW, can be heard normally as far as deliberate communication is concerned.